# Main effects and multiple comparisons for binary data

Tags: r, regression, anova, multiple-comparisons, binary-data

Lets say I have data of the following format in R:

```
group <- sample.int(4, size=50, replace=T)
endorsement <- sample(c(0,1), size=50, replace=T)
df <- data.frame(group, endorsement)
```

Printed:

```
> head(df)
 group endorsement
     1           0
     3           1
     4           0
     2           1
     2           1
     2           1
```

Each row represents an individual. `group` is a grouping variable that indicates their membership in 1 of 4 groups. `endorsement` is whether that individual endorses a particular item

My goal is to determine:

1. Whether there is an overall effect of `group`, which would indicate whether theres a difference between the groups with regards to how much they each endorse the item. This would be analogous to a main effect in ANOVA
2. Given a significant main effect, which pairwise differences between groups are significant? Analogous to a post-hoc test like Tukey's HSD

I understand the analysis I want to do from an ANOVA perspective, however, the ANOVA model doesn't quite fit when I have a binary DV

**My first question is, if I were to use an ANOVA for binary data, what negative effect would that have on my inference and interpretation?**

Ive thought about using logistic regression for this given the binary response:

```
glm(endorsement ~ factor(group), data=df, family=binomial(logit))
```

However, when running a GLM model in R I dont get an F test for what would be the overall main effect of `group` so I can't accomplish goal #1 above

I've also thought about running a chi-square test with count data for each group and compare the count distribution against a null distribution where each group has the same count. This, I believe, would give me something analogous to a main effect of `group` but I'm not sure how I would then go on to compute pairwise differences between each group to accomplish goal #2

**So my second question is, what technique could I use that would allow me to accomplish both goals when my response is binary?**

Comment: use summary(glm(endorsement ~ ...)) to get the p-value for the main effect.

Comment: `summary()` doesnt provide a main effect F test for `glm` models, only for regular `lm`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
model <- glm(endorsement ~ factor(group), data=df, family=binomial(logit))

library("car")
Anova(model)
```

This creates an analysis of deviance table which is like an anova table but it uses a chi-square test.

For the comparisons:

```
library("lsmeans")
lsmeans(model, pairwise ~ group)                      # on the logit scale
lsmeans(model, pairwise ~ group, type = "response")   # on the probability scale
```

The comparisons in the 2nd call are actually in terms of odds ratios (as will be shown in annotations below the output), because the differences of logits (1st `lsmeans` call) are back-transformed from the log scale.

Comment: Ive never seen analysis of deviance before, what is the (null) hypothesis being tested in this case? i.e. how would I interpret the results of the chi square test?

Comment: I think we are at the point of having led you in the right direction.