# Generalized linear mixed effects in repeated measures analysis

Tags: r, regression, generalized-linear-model, lme4-nlme, post-hoc

I'm new here and my question might be a bit long. Sorry in advance.
I want to analyze two groups of patients in repeated measures, and to investigate whether there is a significant difference over time between groups.
My data consist of one dependent variable (dichotomous- 0/1) and two independent variables (group: A,B and time: time1, time2,...time6).

[image]

I used the generalized linear mixed model, and the results are as follows:

```
data2$group <- relevel(data2$group, ref = "groupA") 
data2$time <- relevel(data2$time, ref = "time1") 
model <- glmer(score ~ time * group + (1 | subject), data = data2, family = binomial("logit"), control = glmerControl(optimizer = "bobyqa"), nAGQ = 0)
summary(model, correlation = FALSE)

Fixed effects:
                       Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)             -1.5469     0.4135  -3.741 0.000183 ***
timetime2                2.0747     0.4826   4.299 1.71e-05 ***
timetime3                3.9292     0.6081   6.462 1.03e-10 ***
timetime4                4.7745     0.7422   6.433 1.25e-10 ***
timetime5                5.9804     1.1096   5.390 7.06e-08 ***
timetime6                5.9804     1.1096   5.390 7.06e-08 ***
groupgroupB             -0.5176     0.6253  -0.828 0.407803    
timetime2:groupgroupB    1.7377     0.7613   2.282 0.022461 *  
timetime3:groupgroupB    1.2571     0.9841   1.277 0.201426    
timetime4:groupgroupB    0.8736     1.1528   0.758 0.448542    
timetime5:groupgroupB   15.9771  1397.4011   0.011 0.990878    
timetime6:groupgroupB   15.9771  1397.4011   0.011 0.990878    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

I deduce the following from the result: With reference Group A and Time 1 point, the score changes over time and there is no difference between groups; however, time * group interaction is significant.

My questions are:

1. Is the conclusion I stated above correct?
2. When I use `car::Anova` , there is no time * group interaction. Is it wrong to do the following analysis? What's the difference between them?

```
Anova(model, type = 3)
Response: score
              Chisq Df Pr(>Chisq)    
(Intercept) 13.9981  1   0.000183 ***
time        83.3778  5  < 2.2e-16 ***
group        0.6852  1   0.407803    
time:group   5.3224  5   0.377808    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

3. Is post hoc analysis necessary? Is it binary comparison if I look for significance by changing the references with `relevel`? For example with `time : group` command:

```
data2$group <- relevel(data2$group, ref = "groupB") 
data2$time <- relevel(data2$time, ref = "time4") 
model <- glmer(score ~ time : group + (1 | subject), data = data2, family = binomial("logit"), control = glmerControl(optimizer = "bobyqa"), nAGQ = 0)
summary(model, correlation = FALSE)

Fixed effects:
                       Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)              0.5278     0.3703   1.425 0.154025    
timetime4:groupgroupB    3.0559     0.8696   3.514 0.000442 ***
timetime3:groupgroupB    2.5941     0.7605   3.411 0.000648 ***
timetime1:groupgroupB   -2.5923     0.5976  -4.338 1.44e-05 ***
timetime6:groupgroupB   19.3653  1397.4007   0.014 0.988943    
timetime5:groupgroupB   19.3653  1397.4007   0.014 0.988943    
timetime2:groupgroupB    1.2201     0.5764   2.117 0.034274 *  
timetime4:groupgroupA    2.6998     0.7079   3.814 0.000137 ***
timetime3:groupgroupA    1.8545     0.5675   3.268 0.001083 ** 
timetime1:groupgroupA   -2.0747     0.4826  -4.299 1.71e-05 ***
timetime6:groupgroupA    3.9057     1.0864   3.595 0.000324 ***
timetime5:groupgroupA    3.9057     1.0864   3.595 0.000324 ***
```

In this analysis, time2:groupA is dropping. So can I say this: Group A is significant different in the Time 2 point than Group B?

4. If above mentioned commands wrong, is this post-hoc analysis true in below? Can I use `emm` function to compare binomial variables? Or is it only appropriate for continuous data?  It is stated that it can be used in many R articles, but I am not sure. In this analysis, Group A is not differ in the Time 2 point than Group B.

```
summary(glht(model, emm(pairwise ~ time * group)), test=adjusted(type="holm"))

Linear Hypotheses:
                                   Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
time1 groupA - time2 groupA == 0 -2.075e+00  4.826e-01  -4.299 0.000874 ***
time1 groupA - time3 groupA == 0 -3.929e+00  6.081e-01  -6.462 6.52e-09 ***
time1 groupA - time4 groupA == 0 -4.775e+00  7.422e-01  -6.433 7.78e-09 ***
time1 groupA - time5 groupA == 0 -5.980e+00  1.110e+00  -5.390 3.81e-06 ***
time1 groupA - time6 groupA == 0 -5.980e+00  1.110e+00  -5.390 3.81e-06 ***
time1 groupA - time1 groupB == 0  5.176e-01  6.253e-01   0.828 1.000000    
time1 groupA - time2 groupB == 0 -3.295e+00  6.050e-01  -5.446 2.84e-06 ***
time1 groupA - time3 groupB == 0 -4.669e+00  7.825e-01  -5.967 1.43e-07 ***
time1 groupA - time4 groupB == 0 -5.131e+00  8.889e-01  -5.772 4.55e-07 ***
time2 groupA - time2 groupB == 0 -1.220e+00  5.764e-01  -2.117 1.000000 
.....
.....
```

5. Last one:) May I compare the groups in this way:

```
model_postHoc <- glmer(score ~ group + (1 | subject), data = data2[data2$time == "time2", ], family = binomial("logit"), control = glmerControl(optimizer = "bobyqa"), nAGQ = 0)
summary(model_postHoc, correlation = FALSE)

Random effects:
 Groups  Name        Variance  Std.Dev. 
 subject (Intercept) 2.329e-12 1.526e-06
Number of obs: 104, groups:  subject, 104

Fixed effects:
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)  
(Intercept)   0.4700     0.2850   1.649   0.0992 .
groupgroupB   1.0940     0.4643   2.356   0.0185 *
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

In this analyze, there is a difference between the groups in the Time 2 point. I am confused.
I am aware that this method can be reduced the statistical power, and increase Type 1 error.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is something weird about your data: Why are the coefficients for time 5 and time 6 the same for both groups A and B? Also see huge the standard errors for time 5 and time 6 in group B. I wouldn't be making conclusions before fixing this.

Comment: @dipetkov thanks for the comment. The dependent variable is a count variable (like yes or no). It is because the number of cases with the same degree was also equal at time 5 and time 6 (in group A: 51 yes, 1 no in both times; in group B: 52 yes, 0 no in both times). In terms of the standard errors, I can't comment because my statistical knowledge is not sufficient to interpret this; sorry.

Comment: I want to edit the comment. The dependent variable was determined by whether a subject could perform a test or not.

Comment: Of course, complete separation! [High p-values for logistic regression variable that perfectly separates?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/102695/high-p-values-for-logistic-regression-variable-that-perfectly-separates)

Comment: @dipetkov thanks for the answer and reference. I read the reference, and Frank Harrell suggest using likelihood ratio tests in such cases. I analyzed the model with the Type III Wald chisquare tests. Is that wrong you think?

Comment: You are assuming equal correlation no matter how large the time gap (compound symmetry).  This is [unrealistic](https://www.fharrell.com/post/re).  Also for your dependent variable I'd use a semiparametric (ordinal) model.

Comment: @FrankHarrell thanks for the comment. Is the reason of your suggestion that using a semiparametric model related to huge standard errors?

Comment: No, and I should have noted that your Y is binary so you can stay with a parametric binary logistic model.  My main worry is that the correlation pattern is not being modeled correctly.

Comment: Thank you @FrankHarrell. I will investigate this issue and write the results I reach. Thanks again.

Comment: @FrankHarrell I tried to plot a variogram graph to investigate the correlation pattern, but I did not succeed. You give an example in your [e-book](https://hbiostat.org/doc/rms.pdf); however,  ```{r}
gls
``` function is not appropriate for my data because of binary dependent variable. Do you have any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: See the displays at http://hbiostat.org/rmsc/markov.html#correlation-structure - your binary Y setup is a special case of ordinal Y and will work fine with the approach used there.

Comment: @FrankHarrell thank you.

Answer (score 0):

After my research and consulting with some statisticians, I would like to answer my question and open my answer for discussion.

Since there is a categorical variable with more than two levels (time1, time2,.., time6), it is difficult to interpret the results with the `summary()` function as @gungReinstateMonica answered a question in [here.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/115304/interpreting-output-from-anova-when-using-lm-as-input) For example, in the result below, result of `timetime2:groupgroupB` present that additional difference between groupB and groupA when time2 OR additional difference between time2 and time1 when groupB ([reference](https://stats.oarc.ucla.edu/r/faq/how-can-i-test-contrasts-in-r/)). But I am mainly interested in the interaction between group and time. Maybe pairwise comparisons can be made regardless of whether the interaction is significant or not; however, I am not sure (please interpret this inference). So, I think, `summary()` function cannot be an option for my purpose. Thus, the third, fourth, and fifth propositions are also disabled.

```
data2$group <- relevel(data2$group, ref = "groupA") 
data2$time <- relevel(data2$time, ref = "time1") 
model <- glmer(score ~ time * group + (1 | subject), data = data2, family = binomial("logit"), control = glmerControl(optimizer = "bobyqa"), nAGQ = 0)
summary(model, correlation = FALSE)

Fixed effects:
                       Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)             -1.5469     0.4135  -3.741 0.000183 ***
timetime2                2.0747     0.4826   4.299 1.71e-05 ***
timetime3                3.9292     0.6081   6.462 1.03e-10 ***
timetime4                4.7745     0.7422   6.433 1.25e-10 ***
timetime5                5.9804     1.1096   5.390 7.06e-08 ***
timetime6                5.9804     1.1096   5.390 7.06e-08 ***
groupgroupB             -0.5176     0.6253  -0.828 0.407803    
timetime2:groupgroupB    1.7377     0.7613   2.282 0.022461 *  
timetime3:groupgroupB    1.2571     0.9841   1.277 0.201426    
timetime4:groupgroupB    0.8736     1.1528   0.758 0.448542    
timetime5:groupgroupB   15.9771  1397.4011   0.011 0.990878    
timetime6:groupgroupB   15.9771  1397.4011   0.011 0.990878    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

I think, I should analyze the model with `car::Anova` [`Anova(model, type = 3, test.statistic = "Chisq")`] (References: answer of @RussLenth in [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/266808/main-effects-and-multiple-comparisons-for-binary-data) and [Dr. Jacob Wobbrock](https://depts.washington.edu/acelab/proj/Rstats/Rstats.pdf) in sixty-sixth page). The result is:

```
Analysis of Deviance Table (Type III Wald chisquare tests)

Response: score
              Chisq Df Pr(>Chisq)    
(Intercept) 23.5614  1   1.21e-06 ***
group         0.1194  1     0.7296    
time       83.3778  5  < 2.2e-16 ***
group:time   5.3224  5     0.3778    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

As a result, I conclude that there is no interaction between group and time. And, if desired, post hoc analysis for the time variable can be performed with a created a new model without the interaction as follows:

```
model2 <- glmer(score ~ group + time + (1|subject), data = data2, family = binomial("logit"), control = glmerControl(optimizer = "bobyqa"), nAGQ = 0)
summary(glht(model2, emm(pairwise ~ time)), test = adjusted(type = "bonferroni"))
```

OR

```
emmeans(model2, pairwise ~ time, adjust = "bonferroni", mode = "linear.predictor", type = "Score")
```

I would be very grateful if you could review my answer and give your comments. Thanks in advance.